# WindowsImagingComponent or System.Windows.Media.Imaging

Tags: windows, bitmap, imaging, wic

I need to work with some bitmaps in managed code and save them as PNG files. Should I use `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.DirectX.WindowsImagingComponent`, or `System.Windows.Media.Imaging`? They both seem very similar, and I'm not sure why I would choose one over the other. Can anybody compare and contrast them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both use WIC, that's why they are so similar.  The Windows API Code pack is retired content, you'll want to use the WPF namespace since it is available on .NET 3 and up and doesn't require a separate install.

Comment: Are you sure the API Code Pack is being deprecated?

Comment: Retired is not the same thing as deprecated.  It just isn't being maintained anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.DirectX.WindowsImagingComponent is in the Windows API Code Pack, which is a source code library that you would need to build into your application. On the other hand, System.Windows.Media.Imaging is included in the .NET Framework.

If you have no other use for the Windows API Code Pack, I would recommend using System.Windows.Media.Imaging. I believe the inclusion of a WIC API in the Windows API Code Pack is primarily for interoperability with the DirectX APIs in the Code Pack, which have no equivalents in the .NET Framework.